# Word for "receiving an assignment"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

> Within a group, there is one leader and a number of non-leader workers. There is a list of published and understood tasks. Non-leaders take on tasks and are accountable to complete them, but the leader does not assign the tasks; the leader is responsible for making sure all tasks are **assumed** and may assign tasks if no one assumes a particular task.

What words can be used in place of the bold **assumed**? I came up with "assume responsibility"

Comment: Try using **accepted**.

Comment: So are the workers expected to complete the tasks voluntarily? And the leader only assigns if nobody voluntarily completes a task?

Comment: Maybe **adopted**.

Comment: @Hank not to complete the tasks, but to take on the task and be responsible for the completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to just use ***taken***.

> ... the leader is responsible for making sure all tasks
>   are ***taken*** and may assign tasks if ...

Webster:

> *Adj*.
>   **2**. **[taken](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/taken)** - **having possession gained** especially by force or effort

Answer (score 1):

If a worker **undertakes** a task, the worker "assumes responsibility" for it.

[Definition of undertake -](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/undertake)
1. To deliberately begin to do (something): *undertake a task.*
2. To pledge or commit oneself (to do something): *undertake to care for an elderly relative.*

As a label for the assignment, we can say the task is **undertaken**.

Answer (score 0):

A good word for this may be *Delegated*

Delegate via [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/delegate)

> Entrust (a task or responsibility) to another person, typically one
> who is less senior than oneself: "She must delegate duties so as to
> free herself for more important tasks", "The power delegated to him
> must never be misused"
>
> [with object and infinitive] Send or authorize (someone) to do something as a representative: "Edward was delegated to meet new
> arrivals"

The idea is you *delegate* work to others, or work has been *delegated to you*. Bosses ensure that all tasks have been appropriately *delegated*.

Comment: But in his context, the tasks aren't delegated unless they're not taken by the group members. He wants the word for how the members take the tasks spontaneously.